# How do I remove all the pages from a tile on the band?

Tags: android, microsoft-band

I am writing an android app that adds one tile to the band with up to 8 pages, each of which contains a textbox whose string is generated from the users input in a listArray. The asyncTask that adds the tile and updates the pages is executed onClick of a button.  The user can alter the items in the listArray and then press the button to update the band. I have all this working so far with one issue:if the original list has for example 8 strings and 8 pages are generated, if the user then alters the listArray to have 5 strings which should generate 5 pages those new 5 pages are added but old pages 6, 7, and 8 stay on the band.  I would like to call for all the current pages for the tile to be deleted before calling updatePages(). The documentation showed how to delete all the tiles created by the app, but is there a way to delete just the pages and not the tile itself? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to adding new pages, you can call `BandTileManager.removePages(java.util.UUID tileId)` to clear any existing pages from a Tile.